# Horizontal Spacing: double \hspace removal?

Tags: spacing

`\addvspace` can be used to create commands which can be stacked together without creating unnecessary padding.  This is useful for creating commands which start and end with `\addvspace` so that they can be placed adjacent to each other without using up twice as much padding space as they need.  Does anyone know of a similar command for horizontal space?  I have a number of commands of the form

```
\newcommand{\fooAnd}{\hspace{1ex}\texttt{and}\hspace{1ex}}
```

that I would like to string together, but I only want them separated from each other by 1ex each.  (And I want to use commands in the interim that don't have `\hspace` in them, so just cutting the space down to 0.5ex is not a solution.)  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about an `\addvspace` version for horizontal spacing but in your case you could add an `\unskip` at the begin of the macro to remove any prior `\hspace` or other skips caused by normal spaces:

```
\newcommand{\fooAnd}{\unskip\hspace{1ex}\texttt{and}\hspace{1ex}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\oldfooAnd}{\hspace{1ex}\texttt{and}\hspace{1ex}}
\newcommand{\fooAnd}{\unskip\hspace{1ex}\texttt{and}\hspace{1ex}}

\begin{document}

Text \oldfooAnd\oldfooAnd\oldfooAnd text

Text \fooAnd\fooAnd\fooAnd text

\end{document}
```

Compare the results:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 10):

This is an adaptation of `\addvspace`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@xaddhskip{%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\@tempskipb
    \unskip
    \hskip\@tempskipb
  \else
    \ifdim\@tempskipb<\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip<\z@
      \else
        \advance\@tempskipb\lastskip
        \unskip
        \hskip \@tempskipb
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\addhspace#1{%
  \ifhmode
    \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
      \hskip #1\relax
    \else
      \@tempskipb#1\relax
      \@xaddhskip
    \fi
  \else
    \errmessage{\noexpand\addhspace not in horizontal mode}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addhspace{2cm} % this issues an error message!

x\addhspace{1cm}\addhspace{2cm}x

x\addhspace{2cm}x
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work any more with TL 2020: ``\addhspace ...d \addhspace not in horizontal mode}
                                                  \fi 
l.33 \addhspace{2cm}
 ``

Comment: @Florian The first `\addhspace{2cm}` is supposed to produce the error message! I added a comment to clarify.