# Is it possible to create an assertion of minimum spacing in a command?

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal Spacing: double \hspace removal?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15413/horizontal-spacing-double-hspace-removal)

I'm trying to keep my document as abstract as possible since I'm likely to change representation of the terms I'm using on a regular basis.  For this reason, I have created a number of commands similar to the following:

```
\newcommand{\gtDepth}{\texttt{depth}}
\newcommand{\gnInt}{\textit{int}}
\newcommand{\gtSemi}{\texttt{;}}
```

I can then use these commands to describe a simple grammar rule:

```
\gtDepth \gnInt \gtSemi
```

The problem is, of course, that there is no spacing between these terms.  I would like to write something like the following:

```
\newcommand{\gspc}{\minspace{3mm}}
\newcommand{\gtDepth}{\gspc\texttt{depth}\gspc}
\newcommand{\gnInt}{\gspc\textit{int}\gspc}
\newcommand{\gtSemi}{\gspc\texttt{;}\gspc}
```

Specifically, I want this "minspace" construct to create space only if it is not already adjacent to that much space.  For instance, I would like

```
a\minspace{3mm}b
```

to be equivalent to

```
a\minspace{3mm}\minspace{2mm}b
```

because the 3mm space is larger.  It seems that `\mathop` provides this behavior in a very crude sort of way: things in `\mathop` are padded on the left and the right, but two `\mathop`s adjacent to each other don't create twice as much space.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the objects to be equally spaced or the space between some of them should be different?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The question is tagged "mathmode" and `\xspace` doesn't work there.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't see the tag `mathmode` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just found another stackexchange post that solves the problem.  *shame!*  It's over here: [Horizontal Spacing: double \hspace removal?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15413/horizontal-spacing-double-hspace-removal)

Specifically, I was looking for the following.  I modified it from the original post to remove the horizontal mode assertion; this makes it work in math mode for me.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@xaddhskip{%
\ifdim\lastskip<\@tempskipb
    \unskip
    \hskip\@tempskipb
\else
    \ifdim\@tempskipb<\z@
    \ifdim\lastskip<\z@
    \else
        \advance\@tempskipb\lastskip
        \unskip
        \hskip \@tempskipb
    \fi
    \fi
\fi}
\def\addhspace#1{%
    \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
    \hskip #1\relax
    \else
    \@tempskipb#1\relax
    \@xaddhskip
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Sorry about the dupe!

Comment: There's no need to be sorry, now I know about `\lastskip` :-)