# How to remove consecutive vertical whitespace from commands

Tags: white-space, vspace

I would like to be able to write macros that approximate the behaviour of CSS's `margin`.

For example consider the following:

```latex
\newcommand{\marginspace}[1]{
  % Defines some combinable margin
  % This is what I'd like to know how to do
  % A naive implementation would just be:
  % \par\vspace{#1}
}

\newcommand{\lorem}{
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
  Lorem
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
}

\newcommand{\ipsum}{
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
  Ipsum
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
}
```

So then this document:

```latex
Foo

\lorem

\ipsum

Bar
```

Would be rendered something like:

```
Foo

Lorem

Ipsum

Bar
```

A naive implementation of `\marginspace` would just be `\par\vspace{#1}`, but this puts an extra line between "Lorem" and "Ipsum", where I'd like them combined:

```
Foo

Lorem


Ipsum

Bar
```

Is there any way to get the white space to be ignored if there's already sufficient whitespace above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `\addvspace` rather than `\vspace`, but this might depend on what exactly you are going do to with this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\marginspace}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\lorem}{%
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}%
  Lorem
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}%
}

\newcommand{\ipsum}{%
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}%
  Ipsum
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}

Foo

\lorem

\ipsum

Bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much better answer than mine.  +1

Comment: If anyone's curious about the horizontal equivalent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15413/horizontal-spacing-double-hspace-removal

Comment: Great link @Alec.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your two macros work in tandem...that is to say, if `\lorem` knows what to keep an eye out for (in this case `\ipsum`), then `\lorem` can absorb a few arguments and test them for `\ipsum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\marginspace}[1]{
  \par\vspace{#1}
}
\newcommand{\lorem}[2]{
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
  Lorem
  \ifx\par#1
    \ifx\ipsum#2\else
      \marginspace{\baselineskip}
    \fi
  \else
    \ifx\ipsum#1\else
      \marginspace{\baselineskip}
    \fi
  \fi
  #1#2%
}
\newcommand{\ipsum}{
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
  Ipsum
  \marginspace{\baselineskip}
}
\begin{document}
Foo

\lorem

baz

\ipsum

Bar

\hrulefill

Foo

\lorem

\ipsum

Bar

\hrulefill

Foo
\lorem
\ipsum
Bar
\end{document}
```

[image]